# Pass serial port readings on RPi to remote for automated testing

Tags: python, ssh, serial

The objective of my current RaspberryPi test setup is to read from/write to hardware, and constantly monitor the state/log message stream for test scenarios. The testing code runs on the RPi, and development happens on my local machine (i scp copy the repo over via ssh). I'm using pyserial to access the serial port info: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Goal: While the tests are functional, I'd like to abstract this out so that the code can run on my local machine, interacting with the serial port on the RPi remotely. This would help to streamline development, as well as allowing me to run from an ec2 instance later on for automated testing.

what are some ideas for how to set up this environment?

Answer (score 0):

You could run the [pigpio daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) or the [lg daemon](https://abyz.me.uk/lg/rgpiod.html) on the Pi and access the results from a [pigpio Python script](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) or [lg Python script](https://abyz.me.uk/lg/py_rgpio.html) running on your local machine.

pigpio may be preinstalled depending on the operating system running on your Pi.

Or you could write your own equivalent using network software.